# element typemap + stl_vector.i typemap + ??? --> wrapped function taking list of elems

Tags: c++, swig

Let's say I have an arbitrary non-trivial type `A` that I can write typemaps for. In particular, let's say that I know how to convert `std::strings` into `A` and that I have typemaps from strings in the target language to `A`. I import `stl_vector.i` and `%template(AVector) std::vector<A>;`.

What's the quickest/easiest (or even the 'right') course of action in SWIG to having a function wrapper of `void func(const std::vector<A>& vals)` where the expected input on the target language side is a list of strings (e.g. `['a', 'qqq']` in Python)? Unless I'm mistaken it doesn't appear to Just Work™ (specifically, nowhere in generated wrapper code have I seen the typemap code for `A`).

If you *need* a specific target language to answer, let's say it's Python. I'd rather be able to do this in the general case, though...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have a header file that looks like:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>

struct A {
  A(const std::string& v) : val(v) {}
  A(const A&) = default;
  A() = default;
  std::string val;
};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& in, const A& o) {
  return in << o.val;
}

inline void run(const std::vector<A>& in) {
  std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), std::ostream_iterator<A>(std::cout, "\n"));
}    
#endif
```

We want to wrap it such that `run` can be called with a list of strings, or a `std::vector<A>` interchangeably.

Given that language agnosticism is a stated goal the best way to achieve this is by introducing a little more C++, to help with some type conversions and an overload.

We can wrap the header file initially with something simple like:

```
%module test

%include <std_vector.i>
%include <std_string.i>

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%template(AVec) std::vector<A>;

%include "test.h"
```

Which is then sufficient to run the first half of our Python test case:

```
import test

test.A("")

v1=test.AVec(2,test.A("testing"))
print type(v1)
test.run(v1)

# Here onwards needs some more work though...
v2=["hello", "world", "isn't", "this", "fun"]
print type(v2)
test.run(v2)
```

To start working with the second half of this test case we need to adapt the SWIG interface. I'm going to do this by adding a function, internal to the wrapper and an overload that takes advantage of SWIG's default typemaps for `std::vector<std::string>`.

By adding:

```
%{
// Some glue to trivially convert types
std::vector<A> convert(const std::vector<std::string>& in) {
  std::vector<A> ret;
  std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(ret));
  return ret;
}
%}

%inline %{
// An overload.
void run(const std::vector<std::string>& in) {
  run(convert(in));
}
%}
```

To the end of the initial SWIG interface we've added an overload that works provided the target language has a suitable understanding of `std::vector`. (Most that I checked seem to).

With the version of SWIG that I tested this with running SWIG itself with warnings turned on gave a (spurious) warning about shadowing overloads. This warning seems to be incorrect, because the code generated really did pick the correct overload, based on the argument given.

Using overloads added with `%inline` in the interface file is by far the quickest/easiest way to get this up and running. It does of course require the copy/conversion overhead *and* writing the overloads manually per function. Doing it with a typemap would only require writing a single typemap, but would be very hard to do in a way that is independent of the target language.